# HoloLens 1 stopped connecting to PC over Wi-Fi

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I would really appreciate some help :)

Worked from home, connected normally for months.

Went back to work, same HoloLens, same laptop, different Wi-Fi.

Won't connect now - cannot access the device portal (https://192.168.1.110/).

Can normally acces over USB (http://127.0.0.1:10080/).

Tried:

- 2 networks - office and tethering over mobile
- 3 browsers
- reseting both the HL and the laptop multiple times

I'm using Windows 10.

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: Is that definitely the correct IP address? It hasn't e.g. been assigned a different IP address - can you check your DHCP server, which may be on the router - or an IPv6 address? Can you ping it? (could you ping it before?) It probably won't make a difference, but how does Windows classify these networks: public, private, domain?

Comment: But whilst we can help with some basic troubleshooting if you can't make this work you should probably talk to Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks, Rup! You were right, HoloLens was assigned a different IP address, works now! If you post that as an answer I'll be happy to mark it as a correct one :)

On a side note, Microsoft doesn't seem to support the HoloLens forum anymore (https://forums.hololens.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem was that the IP address had changed: the IP address will be assigned by the network's DHCP server, and is generally persistent once assigned in helpful networks, but when you switch to a different network or different DHCP server the IP address is likely to change.

In home networks or small office networks the DHCP server is probably built into your router. It would be possible to set up an address reservation for the HoloLens in your router's configuration, if you wanted to preserve or change the address, provided both routers use the same IP address range for attached devices.